# How to return new data from a function as a reference without borrow checker issues?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a function that takes a reference to an integer and returns a vector of that integer times 2, 5 times. I think that'd look something like:

```
fn foo(x: &i64) -> Vec<&i64> {
    let mut v = vec![];
    for i in 0..5 {
        let q = x * 2;
        v.push(&q);
    }
    v
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let q = foo(&x);
    println!("{:?}", q);
}
```

The borrow checker goes nuts because I define a new variable, it's allocated on the stack, and goes out of scope at the end of the function.

What do I do? Certainly I can't go through life without writing functions that create new data! I'm aware there's `Box`, and `Copy`-type workarounds, but I'm interested in an idiomatic Rust solution.

I realize I could return a `Vec<i64>` but I think that'd run into the same issues? Mainly trying to come up with an "emblematic" problem for the general issue :)

Comment: *but I think that'd run into the same issues* — did you try this? Why do you think it would have the same issues?

Comment: @Shepmaster I assumed if I allocated the i64's in the new function, on the stack, it would get pissed. But it seems that it works. I'm guessing this is because I am giving ownership back to the caller, so the borrow checker doesn't get upset, i.e. there's no borrow? Is that kind of solution more idiomatic than using a containing heap-allocated structure like Box or Cell?

Comment: You are correct that there is no borrowing involved: you allocate the `i64`s on the stack, then transfer ownership of them to the `Vec`, and then transfer ownership of the `Vec` back to the caller. *more idiomatic than using a containing heap-allocated structure* — a `Vec` **is** a "containing heap-allocated structure". I would say it is more idiomatic to use a `Vec` in this case than a `Box` or `Cell`. In this specific example, you could also return an array `[i64; 5]` since you know how many numbers you will be returning.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I only just realized that you wrote "I'm aware there's Box, Copy etc type workaround but I'm mostly interested in an idiomatic rust solution", but I've already typed the whole answer. :P And the solutions below *are* idiomatic Rust, this is all just how memory works! Don't go trying to return pointers to stack-allocated data in C or C++, because even if the compiler doesn't stop you, that doesn't mean anything good will come of it. ;)

---

Any time that you return a reference, that reference *must* have been a parameter to the function. In other words, if you're returning references to data, all that data must have been allocated *outside* of the function. You seem to understand this, I just want to make sure it's clear. :)

There are many potential ways of solving this problem depending on what your use case is.

In this particular example, because you don't need `x` for anything afterward, you can just give ownership to `foo` without bothering with references at all:

```
fn foo(x: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    std::iter::repeat(x * 2).take(5).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("{:?}", foo(x));
}
```

But let's say that you don't want to pass ownership into `foo`. You *could* still return a vector of references as long as you didn't want to mutate the underlying value:

```
fn foo(x: &i64) -> Vec<&i64> {
    std::iter::repeat(x).take(5).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("{:?}", foo(&x));
}
```

...and likewise you could mutate the underlying value as long as you didn't want to hand out new pointers to it:

```
fn foo(x: &mut i64) -> &mut i64 {
    *x *= 2;
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    println!("{:?}", foo(&mut x));
}
```

...but of course, you want to do both. So if you're allocating memory and you want to return it, then you need to do it somewhere other than the stack. One thing you can do is just stuff it on the heap, using `Box`:

```
// Just for illustration, see the next example for a better approach
fn foo(x: &i64) -> Vec<Box<i64>> {
    std::iter::repeat(Box::new(x * 2)).take(5).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("{:?}", foo(&x));
}
```

...though with the above I just want to make sure you're aware of `Box` as a general means of using the heap. Truthfully, simply using a `Vec` means that your data will be placed on the heap, so this works:

```
fn foo(x: &i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    std::iter::repeat(x * 2).take(5).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("{:?}", foo(&x));
}
```

The above is probably the most idiomatic example here, though as ever your use case might demand something different.

Alternatively, you could pull a trick from C's playbook and pre-allocate the memory *outside* of `foo`, and then pass in a reference to it:

```
fn foo(x: &i64, v: &mut [i64; 5]) {
    for i in v {
        *i = x * 2;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let mut v = [0; 5];  // fixed-size array on the stack
    foo(&x, &mut v);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Finally, if the function *must* take a reference as its parameter *and* you must mutate the referenced data *and* you must copy the reference itself *and* you must return these copied references, then you can use `Cell` for this:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn foo(x: &Cell<i64>) -> Vec<&Cell<i64>> {
    x.set(x.get() * 2);
    std::iter::repeat(x).take(5).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let x = Cell::new(5);
    println!("{:?}", foo(&x));
}
```

`Cell` is both efficient and non-surprising, though note that `Cell` works only on types that implement the `Copy` trait (which all the primitive numeric types do). If your type doesn't implement `Copy` then you can still do this same thing with `RefCell`, but it imposes a slight runtime overhead and opens up the possibilities for panics at runtime if you get the "borrowing" wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Makes it a million times clearer, and glad to know I wasn't crazy! I thought it seemed like the idea was often to avoid things like Box, but if they have no overhead, who cares then i guess? Only question is, would it be considered "more idiomatic" to return a Vec<i64> with i64's made within the fn? To avoid heap-allocating stuff?

Comment: @William, re: `Vec<i64>` being the most idiomatic approach, the answer is yes, and I've updated the above to reflect that. My example using `Box` was just to make sure that it was clear that there are many ways to use the heap. If you had a function that wanted to "return new data" and there *wasn't* already a `Vec` being returned, then `Box` is what you'd use in lieu of it.

Comment: @William also, I wouldn't say that `Box` has *no* overhead, because a heap allocation does have more overhead than a stack allocation. If you *really* need maximum performance (but beware of premature optimization etc etc), you should consider the C-style approach where you pass in a reference to memory allocated in an earlier stack frame. I'll even update the C-style example to use stack-allocated arrays rather than `Vec` to illustrate this.